# DataSkew after doing salting technique - Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, optimization

I would like to ask about a data skewed issue I have in my spark job.
I know if you have data skewed, one of the best practice tips is doing salting technique.
In my spark job, I have to do a join between two dataframe (one of them size arround 5 gb).

Also, I usually repartition by a number and by the fields that I use to join, to control as much as possible the partitions before doing the join. Thus, I transform a join with shuffle to map-join with narrow dependency.

```scala
df.repartition(numRep, colJoin: _*).sortWithinPartitions(colJoin: _*)
```

The scenario is:

- I have 24 executors with 4 cores each one
- I set shufflePartitions on 96
- I avoid automatic broadcast with `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)`
- The number of repartitions before the join is 192 (2*96) (the double of threads). Thus, I have 8 task/partition per executor

The problem is after doing salting, I've yet data skewed and the join takes a long time.

So, my question is: What should I do? To increase number of salting? Doing salting twice or more? To increase number of repartitions? Is there any function to know what partition has the data skewed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a left outer join, having a high number of records with null join keys in left dataframe can result in skew since spark would shuffle all those records to a single partition. In this case, you could filter out the records with null keys before doing the join.

Another approach that I would do, before trying salting, is to perform a data profiling by doing a group by on key columns to see how bad the skew is and to understand the data skew better.

From spark web UI, you can go to a stage and identify which task(or partition) has a skew by sorting it by task duration ( Spark Web UI -> Stages -> Sort by Duration Desc -> Description -> Tasks)

Or if the stage run was successful, by looking at the Summary Metrics for each stages. Below is an example of a data skew:
[sample stage with a data skew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7useB.png)